# Using CrudRepository.save(Entity) to insert an Entity with predefined @ID field using spring-data-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using `CrudRepository.save(Entity)` to insert an Entity with `@ID` already populated.

I'm getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException: Failed to update entity [com.comanyname.repository.Entiy.class]. Id [ed384316-9c22-4b63-90fd-ec02fdac2b86] not found in database.
```

I can understand the issue as  `@ID` field is already populated,
AggregateChangeExecutor [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/aa05b792c36341cea2ef48a0068ba726bb8270bb/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/AggregateChangeExecutor.java#L62) is treating this action as DbAction.Update.

So, I wanted to know if there is any way I can use `CrudRepository.save(Entity)` to insert a new entity with a predefined `@ID` field as I've wanted to use `@DomainEvent` hook on CrudRepository.save(Entity).

I kind of feel that this a bug in `spring-data-jdbc`.
Just wanted an opinion/solution here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Spring [Data Refrence Documetnation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites), the underlying JPA EntiyManager uses three strategies to determine if an entity is new:

> 1. Version-Property and Id-Property inspection (default): By default Spring Data JPA inspects first if there is a Version-property of non-primitive type. If there is the entity is considered new if the value is `null`. Without such a Version-property Spring Data JPA inspects the identifier property of the given entity. If the identifier property is `null`, then the entity is assumed to be new. Otherwise, it is assumed to be not new.
> 2. Implementing `Persistable`: If an entity implements `Persistable`, Spring Data JPA delegates the new detection to the `isNew(…)` method of the entity. See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) for details.
> 3. Implementing `EntityInformation`: You can customize the `EntityInformation` abstraction used in the `SimpleJpaRepository` implementation by creating a subclass of `JpaRepositoryFactory` and overriding the `getEntityInformation(…)` method accordingly. You then have to register the custom implementation of `JpaRepositoryFactory` as a Spring bean. Note that this should be rarely necessary. See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.html) for details.

In your case, using the second strategy might be the most useful. Hope it helps.

### Edit

It was pointed out to me, that the question was not about JPA, but spring-data-jdbc. This is correct but does not change the answer since the same behaviour is documented in [Spring Data JDBC - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.state-detection-strategies).

Comment: the question is not about JPA, iit is about spring-data-jdbc. It has no underlying JPA

Comment: I agree, during my research, I probably had multiple tabs open and used the wrong one to answer the question. Nevertheless, this doesn't invalidate the answers since the same behaviour is documented in the [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.state-detection-strategies). But for the answer to be precise, I'll add it to the original answer.